# Do wounds carry over between chapters (Mice and Mystics)?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

The rules are unclear, and the FAQ on the Plaid Hat website does not address this issue. Does anyone know if any wounds on the mice carry over between chapters when playing Mice and Mystics as a campaign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

Slightly less short answer:
This is indeed not literally stated in the rules. However, our group has decided to start each new chapter without wounds, for the following reasons:

- Mechanically, each chapter is a seperate game. The rulebook states some things that *are* carried over, as opposed to a normal series of games, and wounds are not one of those. Some things are specified as not carried over, but wounds are never mentioned, and so it can be assumed they follow normal game rules.
- Storywise, it would make little sense to have healing happen semi-regularly during a fight and not at all during periods of rest.

That said, the rulebook *does* state that the campaign rules on p. 19 are guidelines and suggestions, meaning there are no "real" rules about campaign play. If you feel it is appropriate to keep your wounds during campaign play, you are absolutely free to do so.

Comment: I accepted this because of how the first bullet is worded. I also appreciated the second bullet. However, it was a hard choice.

Answer (score 6):

No, they do not.  The campaign rules specifically state which items carry over between chapters, and wounds are not listed.  While they also specifically list a few things that are not carried over, if they had intended for wounds to be carried over they clearly would've called this out.  However, they do say that the guidelines are "suggestions", so you can feel free to carry over wounds if you think it would improve your experience.

> The following guidelines are suggested for playing mice and mystics as
> a campaign:
>
> 1. Mice keep their story achievements and abilities earned from previous chapters.
> 2. Mice can keep only 1 search card that they had at the end of the previous chapters. This 1 card is in addition to their starting
>    equipment cards. Mice will always begin a new chapter with their
>    starting equipment cards.
> 3. Mice do not keep any party items, individual achievements, or cheese from previous chapters.